# Styling dynamically-created HTML mobile-compatible?

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working on a way for my company to streamline some of our customer's day-to-day, by allowing them to generate their own questionnaires through our system.

Styling has become a bit of an issue. Because I do not know how long the text they put in their questions/answers will be, nor do I know how many answers (i.e. checkboxes, radio buttons, etc) there will be, I cannot set fixed widths on any elements.

The wish as well is for this to become dynamically scalable to browser width (for mobile compatibility). I've been messing a bit with css "grid" functionality, which works up to a certain point.

Aligning the "question" on the left side, regardless of how many rows the "answer" will take is proving troublesome. Placing the divs inside of a table will automatically "disable" the whole grid functionality.

Any suggestions on making this work are very welcome!

```css
.mainContainer {
  /* Borders temporary, to see if element exceeds max-width */
  width 95%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: .4em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
}

.questionContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(6em, 1fr));
}

.question {
  align-self: center;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 1000;
}

.answer {
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  align-self: center;
}

.answer input[type=text] {
  width: 20em;
}

hr {
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <!-- Start first question -->
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="question">
      This text should, always, be filling the entire row. Regardless of how many rows are created by the elements next to it, and the css grid.<br /><br /> Problem:It should by default have more width than the answers.
      <br /><br /> Problem 2: The answers should now be more vertically aligned to the center, if the question asked is as long as this.
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio1" />
      <label>In tincidunt semper sapien</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio2" />
      <label>Quisque hendrerit tellus nec ex pellentesque gravida.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio3" />
      <label>Cras in odio</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio4" />
      <label>Nunc nec orci eros.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio5" />
      <label>Curabitur in tempor justo.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio6" />
      <label> Integer ac volutpat nulla, vitae congue arcu.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="Radio7" />
      <label>Problem 3: This_one_will_exceed_the_width.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End first question -->

  <hr />

  <!-- Start second question -->
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="question">
      Phasellus ac aliquam ex. In lacinia nisi nec felis vestibulum porta.
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nulla ultricies maximus quam ut fermentum." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End second question -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you create [mcve] with html and css as a sample so that we can see what might be the problem? Without any code or specific problem, the question is too broad to answer. Also using tables for layout is not recommended now days, use flexbox/grid or other modern css techniques

Comment: https://codepen.io/Aseldar/pen/vozXdj

Here's a quick codepen of an example.

Comment: Add the example here as a snippet, there is a button for that in the editor. The question should contain all the information without opening external links that may change at any time.

Comment: Snippets have been added!

Comment: @Aseldar SO even has special Code-Snippets (the "<>" button in editor) to insert html/css/javascript code AND they have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png =)